# Insert date and time as unix_timestamp in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to insert current date and time to activitystamp as unix_timestamp. But i just get 0 as result.

```
INSERT INTO `skadate`.`ow_base_user_online` (`id`, `userId`, `activityStamp`, `context`, `misc`) 
VALUES (NULL, '1402', 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP()', '1', '1');
```

Comment: you're not calling a function. you're passing a string which contains text that LOOKS like a function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL functions should *not* be in quotes:

```
INSERT INTO `skadate`.`ow_base_user_online` (`id`, `userId`, `activityStamp`, `context`, `misc`) 
VALUES (NULL, '1402', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '1', '1');
```

Comment: It's usually a simple thing like that :)